# Syntax Error while writing a python program in vim

Tags: python, vim

I'm slowly trying to convert to writing code in vim, and stumbled upon a problem while writing a python program. I used characters like `'aí'` and `'ã'` and after running the program in the terminal I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

I've set up my _vimrc file with

`set encoding=utf-8`
`set fileencoding=utf-8`

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
The python version I'm using is version 3.6.5 and here's the snippet of the code where the error happens:

```
1 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                       
2 import discord                                                          
3 from discord.ext import commands                                                                                      
4 import time                                                                                                           
5 import os                                                                                                             
6                                                                                                                       
7 bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')                                                                                
8                                                                                                                       
9 @bot.event                                                                                                           
10 async def on_ready():                                                                                                
11     print('The bot is online.')                                                                                      
12                                                                                                                                                                                                   
20                                                                                                                      
21 @bot.event                                                                                                           
22 async def on_message(message):                                                                                       
23     keyword_list = ['hi', 'hello', 'goodbye']                                                                        
24     channel = message.channel                                                                                        
25     for keyword in keyword_list:                                                                                     
26         if keyword.lower() in message.content.lower():                                                               
27             response = f'Bem vindo aí'                                                                               
28             await channel.send(response)
```

More specifically, the error points to line 27.

Comment: *byte 0xed in position 0: unexpected end of data*: your file consists of **one** byte, the byte with hex value ED. Are you sure you saved the file?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (the error message I can produce is very different). What Python version are you using, is this a script or a module you import, any other information you can include?

Comment: Can you give a longer sample of your code? For example: `def α_something(β):` should be valid Python code (though I haven't tried on versions lower than 3.6).